# How to create angular-charts from dynamically generated json from java rest service

Tags: java, angularjs, json, chart.js

I have the following json data from rest service which I have to create a pie chart with in angular-charts using chartjs. This is almost similar to [similar question](http://quabr.com/33840422/is-it-possible-to-make-a-chart-dynamically-using-json-in-angularjs)

```
 {
        "datalist": [
            {
                "total": 99,
                "member": "members"
            },
            {
                "total": 3,
                "member": "visitors"
            }
        ]
    }
```

However I need to get the following styled data for my pie chart

```
$scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
$scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
```

Can anyone help me do that. Desperately need this help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BDW you referenced deleted question..

Comment: Ok Sorry I was talking of the json data displayed there.

Comment: The end result you want is `$scope.labels = ["members", "visitors"]` and `$scope.data = [99, 3]`?

Comment: Thanks Lex I found the answer.